# Is there any `strip`-liked method for a list?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, strip

The buildin `strip` method in python can strip padding substring that meet a custom condition easily. eg

```py
"000011110001111000".strip("0")
```

will trim the padding zero on both side of the string, and return `11110001111`.

I would like to find a similar function for a list. eg, for a given list

```py
input = ["0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"]
```

the expect output will be

```py
output = ["1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1"]
```

The items in the example `input` are over simplified, **they might be any other python objects**.

`list comprehension` will remove all the items, instead of the padding ones.

```
[i for i in input if i != "0"]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `itertools.dropwhile` from both ends:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

input_data = ["0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"]

def predicate(x):
    return x == '0'

result = list(dropwhile(predicate, list(dropwhile(predicate, input_data))[::-1]))[::-1]
result
```

Output:

```
['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1']
```

Answer (score 2):

No list method, but it's not hard to implement such a function: Scan for the desired indexes and then slice to them.

```
def strip_seq(predicate, xs):
    def scan(xs):
        return next((i for i, x in enumerate(xs) if not predicate(x)), 0)
    return xs[scan(xs) : -scan(reversed(xs)) or None]

xs = ["0", "0", "a", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "b", "0", "0", "0"]
print(strip_seq(lambda x: x=='0', xs))  # ['a', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'b']
```

This should work on any of the sliceable sequence types, including strings and tuples.

Comment: I noticed that there is a hidden bug in this function. If the list is not end items that meet the required condition, an empty list will return. eg, xs = ["0", "0", "a", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "b"]

Comment: @ChangYe try the new version.

Comment: `or None` is a very smart solution. It is much better than `len(xs) - scan(reversed(xs))`. Thank you gilch.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-strip with while/pop.

```
input = ["0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"]
while input and input[-1] == "0": input.pop()
```

You can left-strip with `itertools.dropwhile`, but you might have to make a new list.

```
from itertools import dropwhile
input = [*dropwhile(lambda x: x=='0', input)]
```

Or you can while/pop efficiently from both ends by converting to a deque.

```
from collections import deque
input = ["0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"]
input = deque(input)
while input and input[-1] == '0': input.pop()
while input and input[0] == '0': input.popleft()
```

(Also `input()` is already a builtin function, so it's better not to reuse that name for variables.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method. You can use `itertools.dropwhile` to strip left. Stripping right might be possible using a generator function.

```
import itertools as it
stripleft = list(it.dropwhile(lambda x: x==myitem, inputlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

A "basic" solution is given below.  Solutions using dropwhile reverse the input and this may be expensive in certain cases.

The solution below computes the start and end indicies and returns a slice of the input.

This solution works for other types of sequences such as tuple in that the return value is the same type as the input.  This method works for string inputs as well, although `str.split()` would probably be faster.

```
def strip_basic(input_data, predicate):
    N = len(input_data)
    if not N:
        return input_data[0:0]      # empty sequence, new copy for mutables
    i = 0
    while i < N and predicate(input_data[i]):
        i = i + 1
    if i == N:                      # optimization
        return input_data[0:0]      # empty sequence
    j = N - 1
    while j and predicate(input_data[j]):
        j = j - 1
    j = j + 1
    return input_data[i:j]
```

For comparison (in this solution, a portion of the input is reversed twice):

```
def strip_dropwhile(input_data, predicate):
    return list(dropwhile(predicate, list(dropwhile(predicate, input_data))[::-1]))[::-1]
```

Here are some numbers using `timeit`.  Notice that for the pathological case where the input is large and there are no elements to
strip out, the dropwhile solution is around 8x slower than the basic solution. 
In the case where the input is large and all of the elements are stripped out, the basic solution is around
1.9x slower than the dropwhile solution.

```
# input len = 12, output len = 7
# predicate = lambda x: x == '0'; input_data = list('001100101000')

# dropwhile solution:
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.84 usec per loop

# basic solution:
200000 loops, best of 5: 1.51 usec per loop
```

```
# input len = 1,000,000, output len = 1,000,000
# predicate = lambda x: x == '0'; input_data = ['1'] * 1000000

# dropwhile solution:
10 loops, best of 5: 29.3 msec per loop

# basic solution:
100 loops, best of 5: 3.58 msec per loop
```

```
# input len = 1,000,000, output len = 0
# predicate = lambda x: x == '0'; input_data = ['0'] * 1000000

# dropwhile solution:
5 loops, best of 5: 98 msec per loop

# basic solution:
2 loops, best of 5: 183 msec per loop
```